# Boost C++ thread

Tags: c++, http, boost

I've builded the server3 example from :

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

The only thing I did — modified the `request_handler.cpp` for:

```cpp
// Decode url to path.
std::string request_path;
if (!url_decode(req.uri, request_path))
{
    rep = reply::stock_reply(reply::bad_request);
    return;
}

// Request path must be absolute and not contain "..".
if (request_path.empty() || request_path[0] != '/'
  || request_path.find("..") != std::string::npos)
{
    rep = reply::stock_reply(reply::bad_request);
    return;
}

// Fill out the reply to be sent to the client.
rep.status = reply::ok;

std::string filename = "/tmp/test.mp4";
std::ifstream file (filename.c_str(), std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

char buf[1024000]; // 1MB Buffer read
while (file.read(buf, sizeof(buf)).gcount() > 0)
       rep.content.append(buf, file.gcount());

rep.headers.resize(9);
rep.headers[0].name = "Content-Length";
rep.headers[0].value = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(rep.content.size());
rep.headers[1].name = "Content-Type";
rep.headers[1].value = "video/mp4";
```

When I open chrome and hit the server, I can get the video, no problems. When at the same, I open another tab and hit the server, nothing happen. Looks like it wait until the first tab have completed.

The goal is to have a server that handle multiples connections and send multiple files ..

Answer (score 0):

The responsiveness of your server will be based on the following:

- Your use of blocking disk IO calls, so this will hang up a thread while reading in your data.  For maximum performance, you want to use non-blocking as much as possible.
- The number of threads running io_service::run().

The easy way out for you is most likely running more threads running io_service::run().  My guess is that you are running just one thread which is why you are not getting any response in the second tab until the first tab is finished.

The better solution is to look into using non-blocking disk io as well.